# How in a-frame to cyclically play the next sound after the first start?

Tags: aframe

How in a-frame to cyclically play the next sound after the first start?
Animation does not work.

```
<a-sky src="#room" sound="src:#soundstart; autoplay:true; loop:false" rotation="0 300 0" animation="property:sound.src; to:#soundfon; autoplay:true; delay:5000; loop:true"></a-sky>
```

Comment: You want to play a second sound, when the first one finishes playing ?

Comment: Yes! How to do it?

Comment: Using animation, can I start a second sound using "delay"?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a job for an custom a-frame component:

- Play the first sound
- Wait until it's finished
- Play the second sound.

Lets say you have a setup like this:

```
<a-entity manager></a-entity>
<a-box id="first" sound="src: url(sound1.mp3);"></a-box>
<a-box id="second" sound="src: url(sound2.mp3);"></a-box>
```

You can easily manage the sounds with a component as such:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('manager', {
  init: function() {
     // grab the boxes
     let first = document.querySelector("#first")
     let second = document.querySelector("#second")

     // play the first sound
     first.components.sound.playSound();

     // wait for it to end
     first.addEventListener("sound-ended", function() {
       // play the second one     
       second.components.sound.playSound();
     })
  }
}
```

check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/~gftruj-aframe-twosounds)